# Swift/IOS: Accessing objects that are stored inside NSSet

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data, nsset

I have two Modals, **Patient** and **PatientDocument** like below

```
@objc (Patient)
class Patient: NSManagedObject {
@NSManaged var id: Int64
    @NSManaged var fullName: String
    @NSManaged var lastVisitDate: NSTimeInterval
    @NSManaged var documents: NSSet
}

@objc (PatientDocument)
class PatientDocument: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: Int64
    @NSManaged var documentType: String
    @NSManaged var documentUUID: String
    @NSManaged var patient: Patient
}
```

I have Inserted some dummy data for Patients and documents and linked them, a patient can have many documents (one-to-many relationship). On my App (IOS) i have master detail layout with 'Patients' on Master and 'PatientDocuments' on Details section. What i want is to display the related documents for a patient when one of the patients is selected.

Using **prepareforSegue** i can pass the selected patient to the documentsViewcontroller (one that handles the documents). While displaying documents in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** i'm facing trouble retrieving the related documents for that patient.

Is there a way to retrieve the documents associated with the selected Patient alone ?. I tried printing the NSSet **documents** that is inside the patients and it gives me the following output.

```
Optional(Relationship 'documents' on managed object (0x79807af0) <Patient: 0x79807af0> (entity: Patient; id: 0x79808e70 <x-coredata://A7367643-744D-417B-BECE-734260B90D9B/Patient/p2> ; data: {
    careTeamMember = "0x79786680 <x-coredata://A7367643-744D-417B-BECE-734260B90D9B/Account/p2>";
    documents =     (
        "0x7967d260 <x-coredata://A7367643-744D-417B-BECE-734260B90D9B/PatientDocument/p12>",
        "0x7968c0e0 <x-coredata://A7367643-744D-417B-BECE-734260B90D9B/PatientDocument/p8>",
        "0x7967d540 <x-coredata://A7367643-744D-417B-BECE-734260B90D9B/PatientDocument/p9>"
    );
    fullName = Patient3;
    id = 2;
    isCPO = 1;
    lastVisitDate = "2001-01-01 00:08:55 +0000";
    questionnaire =     (
        "0x79689e00 <x-coredata://A7367643-744D-417B-BECE-734260B90D9B/PatientQuestionnaire/p2>",
        "0x7968f440 <x-coredata://A7367643-744D-417B-BECE-734260B90D9B/PatientQuestionnaire/p5>",
        "0x796a72a0 <x-coredata://A7367643-744D-417B-BECE-734260B90D9B/PatientQuestionnaire/p3>"
    );
}) with objects {(
    <PatientDocument: 0x796a6300> (entity: PatientDocument; id: 0x7967d260 <x-coredata://A7367643-744D-417B-BECE-734260B90D9B/PatientDocument/p12> ; data: <fault>),
    <PatientDocument: 0x79694bf0> (entity: PatientDocument; id: 0x7968c0e0 <x-coredata://A7367643-744D-417B-BECE-734260B90D9B/PatientDocument/p8> ; data: <fault>),
    <PatientDocument: 0x7967f410> (entity: PatientDocument; id: 0x7967d540 <x-coredata://A7367643-744D-417B-BECE-734260B90D9B/PatientDocument/p9> ; data: <fault>)
)})
```

(Ignore the questionnaire NSSet in the output, a patient is related to another similar object containing different type of documents called questionnaire)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort the set into an array so that you can display it in an organised way. You can do that directly (using `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`), or you can use a fetch request with a sort descriptor (preferably passed to an `NSFetchedResultsController` so you don't need to load all of the documents to memory at the same time and changes are monitored).

It would be best if your documents had a timestamp or similar that you can sort by, because that makes sense to the user. You could sort by id, which may amount to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I made some changes and got the result i needed :D